# Inline block CSS

Tags: html, css

I get the problem in MY CSS CODE....

The problem is....

Why 'icons friends' and 'icon privacy' do not want to be aligned with the text

Home.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.9.32/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

 <div class="privacy-select">
  <span class="display-ib">
   <span class="mdi mdi-earth"></span>
   <p>World</p>
  </span>

  <ul class="my-dropdown">
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-account"></span>
      <p>Friend</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-lock"></span>
      <p>Privacy</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

 </div>
```

Home.css

```
.privacy-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  dispaly: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

See my coding in https://jsfiddle.net/FIERMANDT/7gygxncp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have made your `privacy-select` div inline block - this means that it's width is as wide as the widest element inside - in this case that is the `display-ib` span as you have made the ul absolutely position (moving it out of the flow)

This means that because this is not wide enough for the ul items,  the ul items will wrap unless you tell them not to:

```css
.privacy-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-dropdown {
  position:absolute; /* does this need to be absolutely positioned - removing this is another way fix your issue */
  top:100%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  white-space:nowrap; /* add this, or alternately give this a min-width, or you could make privacy-select a block element  */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.9.32/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<div class="privacy-select">
  <span class="display-ib">
   <span class="mdi mdi-earth"></span>
  <p>World</p>
  </span>

  <ul class="my-dropdown">
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-account"></span>
      <p>Friend</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-lock"></span>
      <p>Privacy</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS :D, AWESOME FOR ME :D

Answer (score 1):

Change position from `absolute` to `relative`. So that your icons will be relative to the div

```
.my-dropdown { 
  position: relative; 
  top: 100%; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-top: 1em; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute` from your `.my-dropdown` class

```css
.privacy-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  dispaly: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-dropdown {
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.9.32/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

<div class="privacy-select">
  <span class="display-ib">
   <span class="mdi mdi-earth"></span>
   <p>World</p>
  </span>
  
  <ul class="my-dropdown">
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-account"></span>
      <p>Friend</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-lock"></span>
      <p>Privacy</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

also: [JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/FIERMANDT/7gygxncp/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.my-dropdown` container is too narrow - set a width to it and allign it `left: 0` instead of `right: 0` .

Also, you had a typo in ´display´ for the `ul`

Here#s the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w133fbu8/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.privacy-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/1.9.32/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

<div class="privacy-select">
  <span class="display-ib">
   <span class="mdi mdi-earth"></span>
   <p>World</p>
  </span>

  <ul class="my-dropdown">
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-account"></span>
      <p>Friend</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="mdi mdi-lock"></span>
      <p>Privacy</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```